# Can I use 'with' with 'help'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, collocations

Can I use *with* with *help*?

For example:

> What does your sister always **help** you **with**?

Is it correct? (my English teacher said it was wrong)

Comment: You can use *with* with *help*. My guess is that your teacher considers ending sentences with a preposition wrong. See this question for details: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition

Comment: "Hello, thank you for calling NotARealName Help Center! What can I help you with?"

Comment: Can you help me with understanding what bothers you most by including some research you've done on the verb "to help"?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct as correct can be. Some people will argue that you cannot end a sentence with a preposition, but that "rule" was never really a rule, but stylistic advice modeled off Latin. In reality, like German, the preposition is just fine at the end.

If you were to rearrange it, it would sound awfully stilted:

> With what does your sister always help you?

Despite what poorly informed grammar teachers once taught kids, this sort of style should be avoided today.

See Oxford Dictionaries's [explanation of the subject](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/ending-sentences-with-prepositions).